# Node.js: How to pass params in a POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app and a POST route:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){

 //res.send(req.body.title + req.body.body)
 console.log(req.params);
 console.log(req.body);
 console.log(req.body.user);
 console.log(req.body.feedback);
 console.log("ok");
 //return;
});
```

I try to do ~ `$ curl -X POST "http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/test?user=hello"` and I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Router.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:40:22)
    at done (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:250:22)
    at middleware (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:244:9)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:232:6)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:255:4)
    at Object.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:198:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:198:15)~ $
```

Shouldn't that POST work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the parameter you are passing is not on the post body but in the querystring.

According to [the docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#req.param%28%29), to access it you must do:

```
req.query.user
```

Comment: That's because your server is not responding, just logging stuff. Don't you need to do `res.send('hi');` or something?

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer is wrong. It's very clear you wanted something from the request body (given that you say POST), not the query string. You need to make sure the body parser is in your middleware stack:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Once you do this, you can use `req.body`.

(Furthermore, as others have mentioned, your curl is wrong as well. You're putting something in the query string there instead of the request body.)

Comment: the curl works well and the solution I've chosen works fine as well.

Comment: If I could up this answer more, I would. This is exactly what I was missing. Thank you @chjj.

Answer (score 1):

Nope that won't work, because you are adding the args to the URL (thats what you would do for a GET). For a post you need to:

```
curl -d "user=hello" http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/test
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the curl invocation is wrong. Try

```
curl -X POST "http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/test" -d user=hello
```